# Is there a way to write a selenium script for something that will take a long time?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

**Background**

I have a site that allows for companies to advertise. Part of the procedure is picking a date to start and finish the advertising. This means that the advertising should be inactive until its date comes up.

**Selenium**

I'm using selenium tests with Testng, Maven and Jenkins to run headless tests on my server. These tests should cover every area of the site, I have just reached the advertising but cant see how I will test the advertising.

My test needs to create some advertising and see if it comes on-line the next day, but I cant see how to test that with selenium.

I can create the advert with my script no problem but can't see if it comes on-line tomorrow without something stupid like a day long thread sleep.

**Question**

Is this kind of test possible with a workaround? Or is this something Selenium just cant handle? Or perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I see two tests here. 1 create the advert and 2  'activate' it. With automated test you should test both things at any time  with the proper configuration or previous tasks.

Comment: Couldn't you create an ad for the current day, restart the server and test if it becomes active? If that test succeeds, the functionality work for any date.

Answer (score 3):

> Or is this something Selenium just cant handle?

Selenium probably can handle it. You'd have to poll periodically to ensure that some part of Selenium does not decide to time out because it thinks the other part is dead. You could do this by executing an empty JavaScript script (`executeScript("")`). However, I do not recommend this at all because...

> Or perhaps I am going about this the wrong way?

Yes, you are. What you should do is design your tests so that you do *not* have to wait one day to see whether the logic operates properly. Whenever I test processes that will deliver results on a deadline in the future, I make sure I have the ability in testing to not require the test to pause for longer than what is absolutely needed to perform the test. There are many ways to do this, and what is best depends on details of your application which you did not share in your question. Sometimes overriding a configuration option works well. Sometimes changing how the system determines time works well. Sometimes you need something else.

Time spent waiting during testing is a cost that will recur every time you run the test. Over the time of a project this can add up to weeks of productivity lost.

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the calculation of `now` to a service

```
public interface DateSource {
    Date getNow();
}
```

In production this could get the current date

```
public class DefaultDateSource implements DateSource {
    public Date getNow() {
       return new Date();
    }
}
```

In tests, you could have a configurable DateSource

```
public class TestDateSource implements DateSource {
    private Date now;

    public Date getNow() {
       if (now == null) throw new RuntimeException("TestDateSource not setup");
       return now;
    }

    public void setNow(Date now) {
       this.now = now;
    }
}
```

Using an IOC container of your choice you can configure and `@Inject` the `DateSource` into your services. For testing, you can inject the `TestDateSource` and tweak the value as you please.

Example usage:

```
public class AdvertisingService {
    private final DateSource dateSource;

    public AdvertisingService(DateSource dateSource) {
       this.dateSource = dateSource;
    }

    public boolean isActive(Advert advert) {
       Date now = dateSource.getNow();
       return advert.startDate.before(now) && advert.endDate.after(now);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a somewhat similar situation:  I need to test XML message exchange between 2 points.  I had written tests to sent from point A to B, and obviously I could not wait in a unit test until point B sends back a message to point A.  For unit tests what I did was this:

1. You need to write 2 classes that: (1) take care of gathering the "advertising campaigns" for each date, and starts the advertising. and (2) a class that finishes all advertising that is due to finish each day.
2. In the "real" web site, implement a timer process that calls classes created above.  Nothing else.
3. In your unit test (does not have to be selenium), create an advertising with the specific date from-to.  The "to" could be 1 second after the "start" so all you need is a thread sleep for 1 second or 2.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will not provide you with something out of the box regarding 'when to test', but you could use something like Quartz scheduler, using cron expressions to run tests in your suite at certain fixed times. Documentation [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/generated/2.2.1/html/qs-all/)

Comment: I am using Maven to create test packages and Jenkins to run them on my server including scheduling.

Comment: Could you add a Jenkins build task for Selenium scripts and then launch it from the [command-line](http://techieroop.com/run-jenkins-build-from-command-line/#.VfAnyhHvPcs), through, like, a ProcessBuilder object, at a time determined by the test? (You said, "My test needs to create some advertising and see if it comes on-line the next day", so the activation date should be known by the test)